# Wait for 1 seconds then set loading to true

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to show Skeleton on my project, I configured all of the steps but the skeleton is not showing because the it loads very fast, the code i'm using:

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const { search } = useLocation();
  const [isPostsLoading, setIsPostsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get("/posts" + search);
      setPosts(res.data);
      setIsPostsLoading(false);
      
    };
    fetchPosts();
  }, [search]);
```

my question is how to wait for 1 or 2 seconds, then `setIsPostsLoading` to true, I didn't know which code to use

Comment: Why don't you just comment this line `// setIsPostsLoading(false);`  to see how your skeleton looks like? and uncomment it back, once done with testing

Comment: Use `setTimeout` to call the setIsPostsLoading(false), one second later

Comment: To add onto @SonuBamniya's comment (which is great), you could also install React Developer Tools in your browser and then toggle the boolean in the state there.

Comment: Can you try Chrome dev tools =>  `Network` tab change "No throttling" to slow 3g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the `setTimeout()` inside `useEffect` hook as recomended by @plsankar

Maybe something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchPosts = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("/posts" + search);
    setPosts(res.data);
    // Wait for 1 second before setting isPostsLoading to true
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsPostsLoading(true);
    }, 1000);
  };
  fetchPosts();
}, [search]);
```